# Emit signal not working

Tags: c++, qt

when i call `emit changed("From Timer");`It doen't send a signal and slot won't be called.

```
MyTime::MyTime(QObject *parent) : QTimer(parent)
{
timer = new QTimer(this);
MainWindow w;
connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(printMe()));
connect(this,SIGNAL(changed(QString)),&w,SLOT(onChanged(QString)));
}

void MyTime::printMe()
{

emit changed("From Timer");
qDebug() << "i";
}
```

Here is Slot but not change in label:

```
void MainWindow::onChanged(QString name)
{
    qDebug() << "j";
    ui->label->setText(name);
}
```

It prints the "j" but the label no changes.

Comment: `MainWindow w;` is a local variable so it will be destroyed and consequently nobody will receive the message, change it to `MainWindow *w = new MainWindow;`

Comment: It works.Thanks.

Comment: I edited the Question why label not change ?

Comment: I was afraid of that, but the problem is different: it is your lack of knowledge of OOP, in OOP the classes are abstractions, so you have 2 objects: one that creates in MyTime and another one that creates in main.cpp, in In this case the changed signal will notify the object that points to it instead of the window that is displayed. Please review the basic OOP concepts.

Comment: in yout main.cpp: `... MainWindow w; MyTime mytyme; QObject::connect(&mytime, &MyTime::changed, &w, &MainWindow::onChanged); w.show(); ...`

Comment: It did the magic my friend thanks.

Comment: I did not do any magic, I only use the basic concepts of OOP, you should take it into account and this saves us our time.